# What is the best approach for migrate to code-first in an existing database-first multiple .NET Core projects solution?

Tags: c#, .net-core, tfs, version-control, release-management

There is a solution contains multiple .NET Core database-first projects with DDD architecture. There are 4 different databases scaffolded by EF Core for all projects. As we hadn't versioning and release control yet, what is the best way to control versions of either projects and databases?

Is it possible to switch to code-first migration to keep database changes as version?

For now, all projects are on TFS git repository so we have history of commits and pushes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a definite yes according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/)! What you can first do is to scaffold the DB via the `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command first (Which is what .NET calls, [reverse engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)).

What happens here is something like that:

1. Scaffolding the Db will generate the DbContext, and relevant models to the directory you executed the command at (Unless you specify where you want it to end up in the command arguments)
2. You would move and sort the models and DbContext out to their supposed respective locations.
3. Fix the namespace (if needed)
4. Done! Don't forget to inject the DbContext into your DI pipeline

I personally did that back when my team was small, all you have to do is to include the project that contains the DbContext with a `-p` arg in dotnet ef and the DbContext itself (IF the project that contains the DbContext consists of many DbContexts) via `-c` (I suppose DDD would not require you to `-c`)

Something like that. The same goes for the rest of the commands like `dotnet ef migrations add` (To be honest, the same for almost every `dotnet ef` command)

```
dotnet ef database update -c NozomiDbContext -v -p ../Nozomi.Repo
```